# Java ByteBuffer "put" method - preventing buffer overflow

Tags: java, networking, nio, bytebuffer

I want to use the put method of the java nio ByteBuffer in the following way:

```
ByteBuffer small = ByteBuffer.allocate(SMALL_AMOUNT_OF_BYTES);
ByteBuffer big = getAllData();

while (big.hasRemaining()){
    small.put(big);
    send(small);
}
```

the method put will throw buffer overflow exception, so what i does to fix it was:

```
 ByteBuffer small = ByteBuffer.allocate(SMALL_AMOUNT_OF_BYTES);
 ByteBuffer big = getAllData();

 while (big.hasRemaining()){
     while (small.hasRemaining() && big.hasRemaining()){
         small.put(big.get());
     }

     send(small);
 }
```

my question is - is there a better way to do so or at least an efficient way to do what i want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, instead of using the boolean `hasRemaining()`, you can actually call `remaining()` to figure out exactly how many bytes are remaining.

Then you could use a small fixed-size intermediate byte array together with the array-based `get()` and `put()` methods to transfer "chunks" of bytes, adjusting the number of bytes put into the intermediate buffer based on the amount of remaining space.